# Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.orderfood:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example.orderfood:layout/content_home

Tags: java, android

I got an error but i don't know what wrong because a lot of my code is create auto after i choose Navigation Drawer Activity.

**The error have been solve**

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.orderfood:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example.orderfood:layout/content_home: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example.orderfood:layout/content_home: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.orderfood:id/nav_home is not a direct child of this NavGraph

This is activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

//line 12 here
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_home"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is app_bar_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OrderFood.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.OrderFood.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is content_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

//line 16 here
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is Home.java

```
package com.example.orderfood;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.orderfood.Common.Using;
import com.example.orderfood.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.orderfood.Model.Category;
import com.example.orderfood.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.orderfood.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityHomeBinding binding;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;

    TextView txtName;

    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.appBarHome.toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarHome.toolbar);

        //Init Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://androidorderfood-df945-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app");
        category = database.getReference("Category");

        binding.appBarHome.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_menu, R.id.nav_cart, R.id.nav_order)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        //Set user name
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText(Using.currentUser.getName());

        //Load menu
        recycler_menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadMenu();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class, R.layout.menu_item, MenuViewHolder.class, category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder menuViewHolder, Category category, int i) {
                menuViewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(category.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(category.getImage()).into(menuViewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = category;
                menuViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

This is mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:name="com.example.orderfood.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
        android:name="com.example.orderfood.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_cart"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_order"
        android:name="com.example.orderfood.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_order"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: An exception occurred during the creation of a fragment 
likely from a higher-level layout XML. This exception is what caused
the higher-level 'inflation to fail',  you should catch and log 
the root-cause exception.

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace? Android is usually a bit better at saying why things crash.

Comment: @Sam Isn't `navigation destination com.example.orderfood:id/nav_home is not a direct child of this NavGraph` explicit enough?

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is now that part of the stack trace has been put there after my comment...

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry, but I don't check the revisions before commenting.